# Non-blocking Thrift-Server with Django

Tags: python, django, nonblocking, thrift, thrift-protocol

I need to access data coming from a Django webapp via a [Thrift](http://thrift.apache.org/) interface. I'd like to do this in a non-blocking way (eg. using libevent/gevent...) but there aren't many example implementations (in python) around, so I'd like ask here for any examples/hints/experiences!

Please note that this question is about using Thrift, not any other protocol, and I know that there might be better frameworks for this purpose than Django, but using it is also a requirement!

Comment: Can you expand on which part is the server and which part is the client in your situation? I've done Thrift services between both java and python each acting as servers and clients. But I am using threading for that.

Comment: The Thrift server should be on the Django side of the line... I've also seen some Python examples using threads, but I'm curious about a solution using gevent or similar libraries!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done by implementing a thrift server within a [Django admin command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/). See the link for the file structure you will need. In the command file, which you may call "thrift_server.py", you would then implement the usual thrift server as follows:

```
import sys
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand

from thrift.transport import TSocket
from thrift.transport import TTransport
from thrift.protocol import TBinaryProtocol
from thrift.server import TServer

#import thrift files here

#now define the service handler according to your thrift method declaration
class ServiceHandler:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
        #self.log = {}
    def thriftMethodName(self, arg):
        print "hello world!"
        #here you have access to anything in the django framework
        return True

class Command(BaseCommand):
    def handle(self, *args, **kwargs):
        handler = ServiceHandler()
        processor = SaleService.Processor(handler)
        transport = TSocket.TServerSocket(port=9090)
        tfactory = TTransport.TBufferedTransportFactory()
        pfactory = TBinaryProtocol.TBinaryProtocolFactory()

        server = TServer.TSimpleServer(processor, transport, tfactory, pfactory)

        # You could do one of these for a multithreaded server
        #server = TServer.TThreadedServer(processor, transport, tfactory, pfactory)
        #server = TServer.TThreadPoolServer(processor, transport, tfactory, pfactory)

        self.stdout.write('Starting thrift server...')
        server.serve()
        self.stdout.write('done.')
```

Notice that multithreaded server options are described above, though I have not tested these yet.

You could then run the daemon as follows:

```
(virtualenv) /django_project/ > python manage.py thrift_server
```